# I want to passing id (stored in firestore) from page to another page in ionic4 App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6, angular7, ionic4

i want to passing ID that i stored it in Firestore database from page to another page in my Ionic4 App

i have news app that i retrieved the contents from firestore and i want when i click on the news it must show the details in details page 
my code in briefly :

**news.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
        <ion-item *ngFor=" let count of data">
          <h5>{{count.title}}<ion-button (click)="goToDetail()">click for details</ion-button>

            <img src="{{count.image}}">
          </h5>

        </ion-item>
```

**news.page.ts**

```
export class FilmsPage implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllPosts().subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
  getAllPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.collection<any>('123').valueChanges ();
  }
  goToDetail() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/details/{{count.id}}');  
}

}
```

**details.page.ts**

```
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {
  id: string;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private afs: AngularFirestore) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(this.id);
  }

}
```

**details.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  {{id}}


</ion-content>
```

but when i run this code its just showed **{{count.id}}** in details.page.html .. why??? can somone solve this probllem please

Answer (score 0):

If the details.page is to be view in  modal then I think you can you can pass the data to the ModalController to view the new

The best solution is to use a ModalController to pass the single news data to the details.page.